# Carathéodory's theorem for outer measure and inclusion-exclusion property

Tags: measure-theory

I have two questions regarding outer measures, and I was hoping you could help me out a bit.

In our lecture we defined an outer measure as a function $\mu \colon \mathbb{P} \to [0,\infty]$ with the properties:

- $\mu(\emptyset)=0$
- $\mu(E) \leq \sum_{h \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(E_h)$, whenever $E \subseteq \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} E_h$

Now we call a set $\mu$-measurable, if $\forall F \subset \mathbb{R}^n \colon \mu(F) = \mu(F \cap E) + \mu(F \setminus E)$. According to Carathéodory's theorem these sets form a $\sigma$-Algebra and $\mu$ restricted to it is a measure (measure = outermeasure + $\sigma$-additive).

Is it true that the right hand side is to be understood with the convention $\infty + \infty = \infty$? I understand that I am only allow to perform algebraic manipulations on this equation when everything is finite.

Also, we have a exercise in which we need to prove that:

If $E$ is $\mu$-measureable and $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, then it holds that: $\mu(E \cup F) = \mu(E) + \mu(F) - \mu(E \cap F)$

Since this is supposed to hold even when things are infinite, how is this supposed to be understood in the case of for example $\mu(E)=\mu(F)=\infty$?

Looking to forward to you answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should allow for $\infty$ as $\mu$ is a positively defined function, so with this convention, you can say that $\infty+\infty=\infty$, for $\text{finite} + \infty = \infty$. However, as you point out the interesting thing of what about the inclusion-exclusion formula when there is an $\infty$ in it this might become strange as there is a subtraction, and who knows how to subtract two infinite quantities? Well, in some sense it might be better to rewrite the inclusion-exclusion formula as
$$
\mu(E\cup F)+\mu(E\cap F)=\mu(E)+\mu(F)
$$
That way both sides are always positive. When $\mu(E),\mu(F)<\infty$, there isn't any worries about $\infty$. Thus, we should look at what happens if there is at least one of these values is $\infty$. So without loss of generality, we will have that $\mu(E)=\infty$, then the right-hand-side is automatically $\infty$. Similarly, if we look at the left-hand-side we have that $E\subset E\cup F$, so we must have that $\mu(E\cup F)=\infty$, and the left-hand-side is also $\infty$, so this formula makes sense.

Note: if you use the formula for inclusion-exclusion with a subtraction sign things a similar proof can work if $\mu(E)=\infty$ and $\mu(F)<\infty$, since then we would have that $\mu(E\cap F)\leq \mu(F)<\infty$, so we are only subtracting a finite value. The only case where you would have to worry about subtracting infinity is when $\mu(E)=\mu(F)=\mu(E\cap F)=\mu(E\cup F)=\infty$, but subtracting $\infty$ doesn't make sense, so moving it to the other side of the formula like we did above allows you to always make sense of the inclusion-exclusion formula even with infinite values.

Comment: Thanks alot, that helped, I think the problem was simply written badly.

Answer (score 1):

About the first question I would say that $\infty+\infty=\infty$ but this is only allowed because it is guaranteed that $\mu(E)\geq0$ for every $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ so that one never finds the absurd case $\infty-\infty$. Having this motivation it is right, as you said, to perform any manipulation only in the case where every one of those measures is finite.

Having said that it is well possible that the expression $\mu(E\cup F)=\mu(E)+\mu(F)-\mu(E\cap F)$ might not have sense. If the problem was formulated like that it was probably written badly or it was done on purpose to stimulate questions like this. Interpreting the problem as $\mu(E\cup F)+\mu(E\cap F)=\mu(E)+\mu(F)$ the statement makes always sense (with the same convention $\infty+\infty=\infty$) and it is also possible to solve the problem.

Since it was not the question I will not solve the newly formulated problem.

Comment: Thanks! That helped alot.